# Create a pandas DataFrame consisting of a single row of types

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame `df`, consisting of columns `Order, PID, subclass, zoning`. I got their types using `df.dtypes`. How do I obtain a DataFrame consisting of the same columns, and a single row consisting of the type of each column?

For example, if the types are:

> Order:               int64

> PID:                int64

> SubClass:         int64

> Zoning:          object

I want my output DataFrame to be

```
Order    PID      SubClass   Zoning   <--- column
int64    int64    int64      object   <--- row
```

I've tried applying [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) or [unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) on something like `df.dtypes.to_frame().reset_index()` (with various arguments), but it didn't work.

Comment: df.dtypes.to_frame().T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

df.dtypes gives you a series object.
So all you needed to figure was to create a DataFrame from a series object

Try this It should help

```
df_types=pd.DataFrame(df.dtypes)
df_types.transpose()
```